# Total revenue differentiation/calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives, economics

I'm studying a concept that transforms the total revenue function

$TR = P(Q)\cdot Q$

into

$\frac{dTR}{dQ} = (\text{change in P})\cdot Q + P$

Does anyone has an idea how one got to the other please? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the $\color{sepia}{\text{product rule}}$: $\left(u(x)\cdot v(x)\right)^{'}=u^{'}(x)\cdot v(x)+u(x)\cdot v^{'}(x)$.

$$\frac{dTR}{dQ}=\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}\cdot Q+P(Q)\cdot \frac{dQ}{dQ}$$

It is obvious that $\frac{dQ}{dQ}=1$. Thus

$$\frac{dTR}{dQ}=\frac{dP(Q)}{dQ}\cdot Q+P(Q)$$

Comment: would ()/ be in a way equivalent to ΔP? Thanks!

Comment: Usually $\Delta P$ means the difference of two prices: $P_2-P_1$. So the answer is no. But the *differerence quotient* is related to it. $\frac{P_2-P_1}{Q_1-Q_2}=\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta Q}$. Now the *differential quotient* is equal to it: $\lim\limits_{Q\to 0} \frac{\Delta P}{\Delta Q}=()/$

Comment: @jpm78 I´ve made a typo: Here is the correct one: $\lim\limits_{\color{red}{\Delta} Q\to 0} \frac{\Delta P}{\Delta Q}=()/$

Answer (score 0):

What we are doing or should be doing is taking the Partial Derivative.

The analysis in Economics is Ceteris Paribus. The effect that a marginal change in quantity has in the total revenue while everything else is constant.

The Price is a function of Quantity.

For simplicity sake Lets say(100 - Q)

So when you multiply the Price(100 - Q) and the Quantity(Q)

You get

$100Q-Q^2$

The derivative(Marginal Revenue) is

100 - 2Q

You probably want to Maximise your total Revenue so set the Marginal Revenue to 0

A Quantity greater than 50 would actually make you lose Revenue. The Second derivative is negative so you see that anything greater than 50 would make the First derivative less than 0 and the First derivative is the Marginal Change in Total Revenue.

To Maximise the Profit the Marginal Cost will Probably not be 0.

Set the Marginal Cost equal to whatever the Marginal Revenue is.

Or create a function of Total Profit whci will be the Difference of Total Revenue and Total Cost.

I did not understand what exactly what you are asking but intuitevely one will not be able to sell any quantity of a product at the same price(unless the elasticity is 0 an inelastic demand to the price) and that the derivative and the elasticity are negative is the observation Law of Price and Demand. As for MR = MC you really will not sell a good unless the price offered to you is greater than the cost of producing it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was mainly wondering how the first formula turned into the second formula, i.e. the partial differentiation method used

Comment: @jpm78 Was the answer then that we use the Product Rule?

Comment: i think, the product rule doesn't really transform one into the other though

Comment: The Product Rule is Just a Rule to Differentiate. That is why I thought it was the method you were asking for. The concept is that we take the Partial Derivative since anything else will remain constant, fixed, a xerox photocopy.